# python socket server command issues

Tags: python, sockets

Hey so I am making a python server that you connect to using putty or netcat but my issue is when I connect I type one of the commands in #help and it doesn't do anything sorry if you don't understand the question ill just share the code

```
while True:
    conn.send("Command: ")
    cmd = conn.recv(1024)
    if not cmd:
        break
    reply = "" + cmd
    conn.send("\r")
    if cmd.lower() == "#help":
        conn.sendall("[+] Server Commands\r\n")
        conn.sendall("[+] #help - Displays a Help Menu Like This\r\n")
```

so why wont the command go through and echo out what is said in the help option

Comment: Does `cmd` have a newline and/or carriage return?

Comment: return? as in does it come back after being executed if so yes if you mean the actual function ruturn no

Comment: @JohnnyMopp is asking if `cmd` has `\r` (carriage return) and/or `\n` (newline) at the end of it. This would make the test `cmd.lower() == '#help'` fail. But something like `cmd.lower().startswith('#help')` could still succeed.

Comment: thank you very much cmd.lower().startswith("#help"): worked i appreciate it